# How do I produce a linearly chirp signal in spice?

Tags: matlab, test, pll

I want to produce a chirp signal to test my PLL and found out the `lock range`.

There is the `PWL` and `pwlFile` as Spice commands, but I can't understand how can I produce a linear chirp like this :

[image]

This is a Matlab function I have to build such a signal and a binary chirp as well:

```
fmin = 0.1;
fmax = 1e7 * fmin;
numOfSamples = 5000;

f = linspace(fmin,fmax,numOfSamples);
t = 1 : numOfSamples;

w = 2 * pi * f;
x = sin(w .* t);  

plot(x)

binaryChirp = floor(1 + x);
figure,plot(binaryChirp)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To produce such a signal one way would be to use an arbitrary voltage source:
Syntax: `Bnnn n001 n002 V = [expression]`
This is a source with a function you define.

Here is an example of sweeping from 1 to 20Hz in LTSpice:

[image: AVS]

And the simulation:

[image: AVS sim]

I have used the time variable (defined in LTSpice as current sim time) to change the frequency (the (19 * time) part ) to keep things simple, but you can obviously use some other variable to change things (e.g. V or I of another circuit element)

Here is the netlist in case you want to cut/paste:

```
R1 N001 0 1k
B1 N001 0 V=sin(2 * pi * time * (1 + (19 * time)))
.tran 0 1000m 0
.backanno
.end
```

Comment: Thank! Is it a T-spice syntax? I am using Tanner T-Spice? couldn't find Bnnn or .backanno

Comment: I think it's a PSpice syntax in LTSpice, so there may be a few small differences. As far as I know the arbitrary voltage source is a standard component in every modern SPICE, so you should be able to get working. Here is the relevant section on the [Spice 3 manual](http://newton.ex.ac.uk/teaching/cdhw/Electronics2/userguide/sec3.html#3.2.3) page. .backanno is not necessary for the netlist to work (LTSpice adds it automaticaaly, I forget what it does) If you can't get it to work, post your error message/netlist and I'll have another look.

Comment: The nnn in Bnnn just represents the number designated (e.g. B1, B2, B999, etc) Note in the netlist I use B1.

Comment: I just looked at the product page for T-Spice and it says it uses Pspice compatible syntax.

Comment: Fatal Error : "T-Spice1.sp" line 3 unsupported circuit element -> "B1"

Comment: Hmmm - I just tried to find some documentation on T Spice but failed miserably. I also googled for things like "T Spice arbitrary voltage source" but nothing much came back. I suggest looking in the help files and seeing what circuit elements you have available - hopefully there will be an arbitrary behavioural voltage source you can use in place of the Bnnn element I use. I find it hard to believe they wouldn't have one, but you never know. Let me know what you find out.

Comment: Yes I tried too, there is not but i'll use the PWL, thanks anyway !!! :)

Comment: +1. However I think that you should put a 19/2 there instead of 19 to sweep from 1 to 20, since the instantaneous frequency is the derivative of the phase